# Load CSS files using PHP, based on page content

Tags: php

Is this possible? For example, I'm loading all of my css files through my header. One of the things I'm using is the JQuery DataTables plug-in. However, I don't want to load the DataTables css unless the page content contains a DOM element of type "table". I've tried evaluating the page with:

```
file_get_contents($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
```

Which doesn't work. What's the most efficient way to evaluate your page's content in PHP, and load CSS files appropriately? Or, is javascript a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I would say you're over thinking this.
Set a far away cache expiration date on your DataTable css and simply let the user cache the css file.

Answer (score 2):

This could be done using [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), but it sounds like a bad idea to collect the whole document, analyze it, and then add a style sheet header - it's likely to be slow, kludgy and may even hit memory limits in the case of huge tables.

I would tend to say always load the CSS files, and see to it that they're properly cached.

Answer (score 2):

I found it easiest to just set some flags in my parent .php file and have the header file check for those flags and modify output as it gets loaded.

index.php:

```
<?php
    $INCLUDE_TABLE_CSS = true;
    include('header.php');
```

header.php:

```
blah blah blah 
<?php if (isset($INCLUDE_TABLE_CSS) && $INCLUDE_TABLE_CSS) { ?>
   <link rel="stylesheet" .... href="table.css" />
<? } ?>
blah blah blah
```

Unless you've got a large number of conditional settings, then this is fairly simple to manage.

Comment: Yeah, I considered that, but I have about 900 static pages, and probably ~250 have a table element. Need to do this for 3 conditional settings.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a better way to do this.  You can do a deferred inclusion, sometimes called "lazy load".  Within `domready`, you would check for the presence of a given class, let's say `dataTable`.  If there are any elements with this class, you inject a new `<script>` or `<link>` tag into the header with a reference to the javascript or css file containing the needed script/styles.  The `<script>/<link>` tag's onload event will be the callback to trigger whatever initialization you have to do once the script is in place.

My apologies that I can't tell you the jQuery way (I am a Mootools guy), but in Mootools there is a class called `Asset` that manages the creation of the `<script>/<link>` tag and the resulting `onComplete` event.  I'm certain there is a jQuery analog to this.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery! This code looks to see if there is a `<table>...</table>` object, and if there is, it creates a new `<link>` element with your desired CSS file and adds it to the header object.

```
if ($('table').length>0){
    var link = $("<link>");
    link.attr({type: 'text/css', rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'tableStyleSheet.css'});
    $("head").append( link ); 
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but will create a notable flicker, won't it? Seeing as it has to be invoked when the DOM has been fully loaded.

Comment: Well, I would think it will depend on what exactly is being changed with the style sheet. You may be able to visually see the styles apply, if that's what mean by `flicker`